# WPF Disable Window Close and Minimize Button on Tabbing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How can I disable `TabStop` of minimize, maximize and close button of my `Form` in WPF?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yup, I'm thinking of a solution to hide those Button and create a new button then I'll handle its `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop = "False"`. But for now, I'm looking for a way if there's none.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to subscribe to the event and manage it like that

```
e.Handled = true;
```